# What's wrong with this Procfile? (heroku + rails + Resque)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, resque

I'm trying to use a Procfile to spin up my Resque work queue automatically. Here's my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
redis: redis-server
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=7 bundle exec rake resque:work
```

When I push to Heroku, I see in the console:

> Discovering process types remote:        Procfile declares types ->
>   redis, resque, web

But when I create a new background job, it doesn't get executed. It just sits in the queue. If I run heroku ps, I get only:

```
web.1: up 2015/10/15 10:20:23
```

How do I solve this? I want my queues to be processing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the command

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```